# xzgrep and other Compressed Pattern Matching Tools

Tags: algorithm, grep, compression, lzw

I'm experimenting on compressed pattern matching utilities, or more specifically searching for text patterns within LZW-compressed text files.

I'm wondering if the **xzgrep** Linux utility is applying a certain algorithm for achieving that, or is it just equivalent to the regular decompression and grepping, and has nothing to do  e.g.

```
uncompress LARGE_TEXT_FILE.Z | grep "My Pattern"
```

Also, are there any other utilities/software that apply any compressed pattern-matching algorithms (LZW-compressed text files, like http://tandem.bu.edu/papers/let.sleeping.files.lie.jcss.1996.pdf) , preferably with the source code available?

Thank you!

Comment: xzgrep: https://linux.die.net/man/1/xzgrep

Comment: It is equivalent to decompress and grep.